# Error NoSuchMethodError: com.example.new.MainActivity.getActionBar

Tags: android, nosuchmethoderror

I am writing a app in which i am getting ***NoSuchMethodError: getActionBar***, my app supports minimum 9 API Level.

I am also using **android-support-v7-appcompat.jar**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.example.new.MainActivity.getActionBar
at com.example.new.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Used `getSupportActionBar` instead of `getActionBar`

Comment: MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity right? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html

Comment: no hint coming for getSupportActionBar, only showing getActionBar

Comment: so you need support library

Comment: i am already using android-support-v7-appcompat.jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With api lower than 11 you need to use support libraries.

For getting action bar use `getSupportActionBar()`.

**EDIT**

Your activity need to extend `ActionBarActivity`.

Comment: i am already using: android-support-v7-appcompat.jar

Comment: i ticked as useful, will accept in next 6 mins, and one more thing now what would be the minimum api i can use?

Comment: it says in your support library name, min api is 7

Comment: ok last query so at every place in my activity i need to replace getActionBar with getSupportActionBar am i right?

Comment: yes, that should do the work